# How to git pull project and push new branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, pull-request

Git has been introduced on a project, after I've been working on it for a bit.

Now there's a local git server, which hosts the base code, I've been working with and modified.

Now I need to create a new branch on the server, which features the modifications I made.

My plan is to pull(?) the current git repository to a new folder, copy over all the content - which I've been managing locally, then create a new branch locally and push(?) it again onto the server.

This would leave me with a new branch, which I can modify locally and push onto the branch on the server, is that correct?

```
mkdir project_git && cd project_git
git pull <remote>
git checkout -b my_changes    
cp project project_git
git add -A
git commit -m "new branch with local changes"
git push origin my_changes
```

Is this the "correct" way to handle the situation? What commands would I need to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new branch for git server, you can `clone` the repo in another directory (if you have local repo, you can `pull` directly), and switch to a new branch locally and finally `push` to the git server. Detail steps as below:

```
# In another directory
git clone /path/for/git/server
cd repo
git checkout -b newBranch
# make changes
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin newBranch
```

Comment: I've followed your guide and it seems to work, but the local changes are not on the remote branch and git states `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.`.

Comment: Did you use `git checkout -b newBranch`? It seems git still stay on `master` branch.

Comment: Yes I did and after the commit/push the new branch exists on the server, but it still has the original (from the master) content.

Comment: What's the `git branch` say? If `*` is point to master (`* master`), that means you still on master branch.

Comment: You're right, the `*` is on master, how do I switch to `newbranch` then?

Comment: If you don't need the new committed changes exist on master branch, there are two ways you can follow (any one of below): **Option1:** `git checkout -b newBranch <commit id which origin/master point>`, `git cherry-pick <commit id master point>`, `git checkout master`, `git reset --hard HEAD~`. **Option2:** `git reset --hard HEAD~`, `git checkout -b newBranch`, then make changes on `newBranc`h and push to git server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148197/discussion-between-marina-msft-and-saatomic).

Answer (score 1):

Git locally stores all modifications of all branches, and there is only one folder which is your current working space.

When you checkout a branch, your files are modified to the choosed branch state.

When you clone your repo, this unique folder is created, and you don't need to create another folder.

You can do this steps to push your changes on remote repo :

```
git pull <remote>
git checkout -b my_changes
# Do all your changes
git commit -a -m "There are my changes"
git push <remote> my_changes
```

This will create a branch called "my_changes" on remote repo